# displaying confirmation box text on a new line in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

My code here works fine. The line I'm concerned with is :confirm =>

```
<%= link_to I18n.t('helpers.links.remove_from_your_page'), '#', 
            :confirm => I18n.t('helpers.links.confirmation'), 
            :remote_url => reject_review_path(review),
            :class => 'btn btn-danger remove_page_button_pos remove-from-your-page', 
            :id => "remove_from_your_page_#{review.id}" %>
```

My Internationalization file has:

```
Helpers:
 links:
  confirmation: "Are you sure?"
```

So, when the person clicks the button, before proceeding they are given the confirmation box with 'Are you sure?', with Cancel and OK buttons - works as planned.

The problem is when I want to put spaces between lines on the confirmation box. For example, I want to have:

```
Are you sure?

If you do this, that might happen.

If you do that, this might happen.

Cancel     OK
```

I thought what I have below would work, but it doesn't:

(note the 'raw', in :confirm etc...)

```
<%= link_to I18n.t('helpers.links.remove_from_your_page'), '#', 
            :confirm => raw I18n.t('helpers.links.confirmation'), 
            :remote_url => reject_review_path(review),
            :class => 'btn btn-danger remove_page_button_pos remove-from-your-page', 
            :id => "remove_from_your_page_#{review.id}" %>
```

And in my internationalization I have:

```
Helpers:
 links:
  confirmation: "Are you sure?<br/>If you do this, that might happen. <br/>If you do that, this might happen."
```

But I get a syntax error. Any idea how I can get it working? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force line break in Symfony2 translation file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946837/how-to-force-line-break-in-symfony2-translation-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to generate HTML markup, but you can certainly [insert newlines](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#b-paragraph-separator):

```
Helpers:
  links:
    confirmation: |
      Are you sure?
      If you do this, that might happen.
      If you do that, this might happen."

I18n.t('confirmation') #=> "Are you sure?\nIf you do this, that might happen.\nIf you do that, this might happen.\n"
```

Remember to mind the whitespace and tabs. YAML is very specific about consistency with spacing. The standard is two-space indentation and no tabs.