# How to force line break in Symfony2 translation file

Tags: symfony, yaml, line-breaks

In my `messages.en.yml` I have an entry that is used for an email body which is in plaintext, so I cannot use any HTML tags. Now when I need a line break and I add a blank line after, the line break appears in my email body.

But when I try to do a line break with a non empty line following, it does not break the lines.

```
email:
    subject: My Subject
    message: >
        Hello %name%,

        This is my second line

        Best regards,
        John Smith
        Customer Care
```

Arrives like this in my mailbox

> Hello Tom,
>
> This is my second line
>
> Best regards, John Smith Customer Care

I've tried to play around with HTML tags or with the `\n` which I know from PHP. But if I use `<br>` or `<br />` in the translation file and apply the `|raw` filter in my twig file, the HTML tags still appear in my email body. And also if I use `\n` to force a line break, no line break is given and instead, the `\n` appear in my email as well.

Now how can I force the line break if a non empty line is following?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `|`

```
email:
    subject: My Subject
    message: |
        Hello %name%,

        This is my second line

        Best regards,
        John Smith
        Customer Care
```

Comment: Works, thanks a lot. How did you know this? Do you have a documentation reference?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html

Answer (score 15):

In your translations file (e.g. `messages.en.yml`):

```
your
   translation      
      key:
         here: |
                Lorem ipsum.

                CRMPICCO.

                www.crmpicco.co.uk.
```

Accessing it in your Twig template:

`{{ 'your.translation.key.here'|trans|nl2br }}`