# Unable to add a line break in Sylius/Symfony 2 modal box

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, modal-dialog, sylius

I am having a problem introducing line breaks when using SF2/Sylius modal boxes.

In my controller, I have this:

```
    $view = $this
        ->view()
        ->setTemplate($this->config->getTemplate('update.html'))
        ->setData(array(
            $this->config->getResourceName() => $resource,
            'form'                           => $form->createView(),
            'confirmation_message'           => $this->get('translator')->trans('ayrshireminis.cars.backend.messages.delete_category')
        ))
    ;
```

In my YAML, I have this:

```
messages:
   delete_category: |
      Are you sure you want to delete this category?

      WARNING - Deleting this category will delete any of its subcategories and assets!
```

and the markup for the modal box looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   {{ confirmation_message is defined ? confirmation_message|raw : 'sylius.confirmation.message'|trans }}
```

However, the output looks like this (no breaks):

[image]

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946837/how-to-force-line-break-in-symfony2-translation-file) post, but the solution does not work for me.

Comment: Did you tried to add a <br /> where the linebreak should be?

Comment: @KhorneHoly Yes, it just shows as '<br />' in the modal box and this is with and without the `raw` function in the Twig template.

Comment: Is the result the same if you're using `\n` instead?

Comment: @KhorneHoly Unfortunately, yes. Adding `\n\n` just shows the literal value though. It does not parse `\n\n` to two `<br />`.

Comment: You should add the `raw` filter after the `trans` too.

Comment: @Qoop In the controller or in the Twig template?

Comment: In the template. You could also do `{{ (confirmation_message is defined ? confirmation_message : 'sylius.confirmation.message'|trans)|raw }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following construct in my translation file and twig template which works fine for this case:

In the translation file:

```
showBills:
    printDate: 'Date <br> Other Date'
```

Within the template:

```
{{ 'showBills.printDate'|trans|raw }}
```

This works absolutly fine for me!

So i'm guessing that you need something like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   {{ confirmation_message is defined ? confirmation_message|raw : 'sylius.confirmation.message'|trans|raw }}
```